# Excel Find Max of Strings omitting rows

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image]

With the above arrangement of data, I desired an excel formula to find out the max of the strings in column A, ignoring rows for which column B is identified as "Inserted". So, in this example, the formula should yield "Sleep" as that's the maximum string from lexical sorting perspective i.e. Sleep is greatest amongst Sleep, Drink, Fish and Eat

My issue is perhaps different from the traditional index/match solution as I have to skip rows based on the condition in column B

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MIN/MAX on text sort order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33641090/min-max-on-text-sort-order)

Comment: Does it work if you create a new list at column C with `=if(B2="","",A2)` formula ?