# Excel: Min and max of text and blanks

Tags: excel, text, max, min

The Excel 2019 functions `min()`, `max()`, `MinA()`, and `MaxA()` don't work on non-numeric arguments. A [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33641090/min-max-on-text-sort-order/33641532#33641532) gave a formula for performing the max and min operations on text values:

```
{=index(A2:A6, match(0, CountIf(A2:A6, ">" & A2:A6), 0))}
```

for max, with min being the same with ">" changed to "<", and where `{...}` means an array formula entered with `Ctrl-Shft-Enter`.

This works well, but I've found a strange behavior in it. If the given range includes blank cells (i.e., empty, i.e., containing nothing) at the end of the range or inside the range, it works fine, but if it includes blanks at the beginning of the range, the formula returns `0`:

[image: Excel min max on text with blanks]

To complicate matters further, if the blank cells are replaced with empty strings, `=""`, then the above behavior is the same, except that the one with the empty string at the beginning becomes empty instead of `0`.

What is going on here? Why does this formula work with blanks or empty strings at the end or inside the range, but not at the beginning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a disadvantage of `COUNTIF`. While `=A1>B1` will get `FALSE` and `=B1>A1` will get `TRUE` because an empty cell is not greater than `A` but `A` is greater than empty, in `COUNTIF` blank (`""`) or empty will never be count. If you do `=COUNTIF(A1:H1,">"&A1)` you get `0`. So nothing counts as to be greater than the empty cell `A1`.

This is because of the usage of text concatenation in `COUNTIF`. `=COUNTIF(A1:H1,">"&A1)` will become `=COUNTIF(A1:H1,">")` which counts how much values are greater than nothing. That counts `0`.

In array context the `COUNTIF(A1:H1,">"&A1:H1)` gets `{0,5,0,4,3,2,0,1}` and so `MATCH(0;{0,5,0,4,3,2,0,1},0)` gets `1`. Then `INDEX(A1:H1,1)` gets `A1` which is empty. So the Formula shows `0` like `=A1` also would do.

You would see this when using Evaluate Formula in Excel.

One could append a space behind the seach criteria in `COUNTIF`. So empty or blank would be handled like a space. And to each other cell value simply a space gets appended, what not should be problematic here.

```
{=INDEX(A1:H1,MATCH(0,COUNTIF(A1:H1,">"&A1:H1&" "),0))}
```

should work.

Since `COUNTIF` is able using asterisk (`*`) used as the wildcard character to match any character, we also could append `*` instead of the space.

```
{=INDEX(A1:H1,MATCH(0,COUNTIF(A1:H1,">"&A1:H1&"*"),0))}
```

Simply try what fits better.

Comment: Can you clarify "will never be count"? Your post doesn't seem to explain the apparent paradox that you will have two entries simultaneously considered as having no other entries greater than them. For example, with `A1`, `B1`, `C1` containing "A", "B", "C", and `D1` being empty, the formula `=COUNTIF($A1:$D1,">"&A1)`, entered into `A2` and copied to `D2`, will return zero for "C" and zero for the empty cell. But this can only mean that "C" and an empty cell are 'equal' in terms of their 'order' as determined by `COUNTIF`.

Comment: I don't understand the explanation, but the workaround of adding the space works, at least in the simple test spreadsheet shown in the question. So thank you for the solution.

Comment: And we could of course reconstruct that example arbitrarily such that we end up with the conclusion that ANY string - not just "C" - is considered as being of an identical 'rank' to an empty cell.

Comment: @Jos Woolley: "But this can only mean that "C" and an empty cell are 'equal' in terms of their 'order' as determined by `COUNTIF`.": No, it only means that there are 0 values greater than `C` and also 0 values greater than nothing.